# is there any in-built date and time validator in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have written a custom validator for date and time but my requirement is  to add in-built date and time validator, so is there any in-built validator in angular .

Comment: Nope there is not ,Could you elaborate a bit more  what is your requirement ? what you have tried so far and what went wrong with current approach and do share relevant code

Comment: I validate the date and time by writing my own validation functions by using regular expression. now i dont use any custom functions to validate date and time, i want in-built libraries for validation for example if month is > 12 it should show some appropriate msz and if day is > 31 it should throw some error msz like that i want

Comment: So you need to build a custom validator for it,I will help you out before that  share the requirements and be specific

Comment: I already created custom validator, i don't want custom, i need if any in-built validators I'll import that i can use that.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/DateValidator